# Facing issue using Action Bar in Python kivy Application

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am working on developing an application using Kivy. I am using Kivy ActionBar for creating a menu bar for my application.

Kindly refer to the image attached[image]

I want to remove the Kivy icon and move the other options(file / edit) to the left. Please find the snippet of my code.

```
menuAcBar  = ActionBar(pos_hint={'top': 1.3})
menuAcView = ActionView()
menuAcBar.add_widget(menuAcView)
menuAcPrevious = ActionPrevious(with_previous=False)

menuAcView.add_widget(menuAcPrevious)
menuAcView.add_widget(ActionButton(text="File"))
menuAcView.add_widget(ActionButton(text="Edit"))
menuAcView.add_widget(ActionButton(text="Documents"))
menuAcView.add_widget(ActionButton(text="help"))

self.add_widget(menuAcBar)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right on `ActionPrevious` you can set `app_icon`. It's a little bit lower in [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.actionbar.html#kivy.uix.actionbar.ActionPrevious). You can set `app_icon_width/height` for size of the icon or even remove it with `app_icon=''`, but it'll leave white rectangle instead of a "transparent". Leave app_icon be and set only width and height to make it invisible.

The `ĄctionPrevious` has `ActionItem`'s minimum_width property, therefore you need to change it like this:

```
menuAcPrevious = ActionPrevious(with_previous=False,
                         app_icon=<your_image>,
                         app_icon_width=1,
                         app_icon_height=0,
                         minimum_width=10,
                         size_hint_x: None)
```

**Edit:**
It seems that `ActionPrevious` leaves additional unused space even if `title=''` and `minimum_width=1` and you can't access the damn thing through children because it's [unregistered](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/actionbar.py#L708), therefore the only thing I came up with is resizing it so you won't see it anymore:

```
ActionPrevious(
    size_hint_x = None,
    width = 0,
    app_icon_width = 0.1,
    with_previous = False)
```

Comment: Hey KeyWeeUsr, Thanks for your reply. for my application, I do not want any icon set, also the other buttons(File / Edit) , I want them to be left aligned, like we have in MS Word

Comment: Hi KeyWeeUser, Thanks a lot!! the above snippet worked for me, The buttons (File /Edit) are partially left aligned, i.e., I see some gap before File button. Could you help me with this. I tried to reduce the min_width and  kept the app_icon as ''(as required)  but, it didn't work for me

Comment: Maybe you have another button or widget before `File`? Or simply change `minimum_width` to smaller number. Of course there will be a gap on the left side of ActionPrevious, because it consists of 3-4 widgets such as Image and Label.

Comment: as per my requirement, I do not want an icon hence, I have used app_icon as '' and set the min_width as 1. Their are no other buttons / Label present before "File Button" even then, I get some gap before File, the gap size is closely equal to 2 buttons sizes.

Comment: Have you set `size_hint_x: None`? You need to set this for widgets which parent can use `size_hint` of its children otherwise it will ignore fixed size (size, width, min_width,...). The example works for me.

Comment: Pls find the config that i am working with :  menuAcPrevious = ActionPrevious(with_previous=False, app_icon='', app_icon_width=1, app_icon_height=0, minimum_width=1, size_hint_x=None).  Even with this config i am getting the gaps before my "File" Button