# Remove Action Bar Icon Kivy

Tags: python, android-actionbar, kivy

I am having Code as above for my action bar in kivy

```html
ActionBar:
  background_color:0,191,255,0.5
  pos_hint: {'top':1}
  
  ActionView:
   ActionPrevious:
    with_previous: False
    text:"    [b]Dhobiwala.com[/b]"
    
    app_icon:""
                ### I make app_icon as a blank string...but it takes default icon...I totally want to remove icon from my action bar

    markup:True
    font_size:"16dp"
    on_release:root.Show_Devlopers_Info()
```

as per above code...I want to remove icon from status bar....I can not even found anything in documentation of Kivy...Anyone has some Idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facing issue using Action Bar in Python kivy Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200538/facing-issue-using-action-bar-in-python-kivy-application)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like disabling an icon is impossible.
Reference: Kivy sources @ github (https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/856b305c0c876e53e802f1ac9ae16c21fa91ac1e/kivy/uix/actionbar.py#L214).
Relevant part:

```
if not self.app_icon:
        self.app_icon = 'data/logo/kivy-icon-32.png'
```

You may try to circumvent this by using a small completely transparent image as an icon.

Also, you can try to reduce the size of an icon to 0. Have a look at properties `app_icon_width` and `app_icon_height`: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.actionbar.html#kivy.uix.actionbar.ActionPrevious.app_icon_height

Comment: Ya But I Also Want to Remove That Space As Well...Icon Doesn't Resize Automatically as JAVA Made Android Apps...So It Makes Trouble...If There is a way to remove icon and space held by it ...So it will do trick for me...Thanks

Comment: If it Readjust ITS Size It would Be Also Great..Because Sometime Icon Overlap Other ActionBar Widget...Any Solution for it to be set as per different different resolution because its android app

Comment: I edited the answer to include info on app_icon_height / app_icon_width. I'm not sure it would work, but it doesn't hurt to try :)

Comment: You can increase my REPUTATION FOR THIS GOOD QUESTION...Thanks

Comment: Set `app_icon_width: 1` and `app_icon_height: 1` is working. If you set it to 0, it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Please read the in-code comments in order to *Frankenstein* your preferred  method of hiding various aspects of `ActionPrevious`; removing it doesn't seem to be an option and `DropDown` was *no joy* when I tried it on `Kivy v1.10.0`, but one is able to hide portions or the whole thing from view.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

## Un-comment if you wish to add to the action view via Python
# from kivy.uix.actionbar import ActionButton, ActionGroup

kv = """
<SomeLayout_GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    rows: 2
    row_force_default: True
    rows_minimum: {0: ActionBar.height, 1: self.height - ActionBar.height}
    SomeMenu_ActionBar:
        id: ActionBar

<SomeMenu_ActionBar@ActionBar>:
    ActionView:
        id: ActionView
        ## Choose one of the following three pre-coded options
        HiddenIcon_ActionPrevious:
        # HiddenText_ActionPrevious:
        # Hidden_ActionPrevious:

        ## Do the ActionGroup(s) with ActionButton(s) within thing
        ActionGroup:
            id: App_ActionGroup
            mode: 'spinner'
            text: 'App'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Settings'
                on_press: app.open_settings()
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Quit'
                on_press: app.get_running_app().stop()

        ActionGroup:
            id: File_ActionGroup
            mode: 'spinner'
            text: 'File'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Open'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Save'

## Inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36201399/2632107
##  Hide just the icon, but keep the text, note though
##  that one will lose the 'on_press' and similar methods
<HiddenIcon_ActionPrevious@ActionPrevious>:
    title: app.title if app.title is not None else 'Action Previous'
    with_previous: False
    app_icon: ''
    app_icon_width: 0
    app_icon_height: 0
    ## Comment out the following two lines if you wish to have
    ##  ActionGroup(s) and or ActionButtion(s) pushed to the right
    size_hint_x: None
    width: len(self.title) * 10

## Keep the icon and UI methods but hide the text
<HiddenText_ActionPrevious@ActionPrevious>: #
    with_previous: False
    on_press: print(self)
    title: ''

## Hide everything
<Hidden_ActionPrevious@ActionPrevious>:
    with_previous: False
    on_press: print(self) ## method that will not be called easily
    title: '' ## Try placing text here, only a few pixels should show
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 0, 0
"""


class SomeLayout_GridLayout(GridLayout):
    pass


class SomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        ## Cannot set this in '__init__' for some reason
        self.title = 'Some Sweet App'

        Builder.load_string(kv)

        some_layout = SomeLayout_GridLayout()
        ## Uncomment next line if ya wish to use 'add_widget'
        ##  method on ActionView and add ActionGroup(s) and/or
        ##  ActionButton(s) via Python
        # some_actionview = some_layout.ids.ActionBar.ids.ActionView
        return some_layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SomeApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a hack but since `kivy.uix.actionbar.ActionPrevious` is actually a subclass of `BoxLayout`, you can actually use method like `remove_widget()` or  `clear_widgets()` to manipulate its content after you create it:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
<MyWidget>:
    ap: ap
    ActionBar:
        background_color:0,191,255,0.5
        pos_hint: {'top':1}

        ActionView:
            ActionPrevious:
                id: ap
                with_previous: False
                text:"    [b]Dhobiwala.com[/b]"

                markup:True
                font_size:"16dp"
"""

Builder.load_string(kv)

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(*args)
        self.ap.clear_widgets()

class MyButtonsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyButtonsApp().run()
```

Comment: If you found this question interesting increasing my reputation y clicking +1 because this question can help full to all other people..Thanks

Comment: the text is not displayed in the ActionPrevious, its just blank

Answer (score 1):

### Kivi 2.0.0

To easily remove the logo in an `ActionBar` just set the to an empty string to its `ActionPrevious` Children.

```
ActionPrevious:
    title: 'Title'
    with_previous: False
    app_icon: ''
```

### Run this script as an example

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
ActionBar:
    pos_hint: { 'top': 1 }
    background_color: [0, 1, .76, 1]
    background_image: ''
    ActionView:    
        ActionPrevious:
            title: 'Title'
            with_previous: False
            app_icon: ''    # Set the Icon to an empty String           
        ActionOverflow:
        ActionButton:
            text: 'Settings'
            on_press: app.open_settings()
        ActionButton:
            text: 'Quit'
            on_press: app.get_running_app().stop()
'''))
```

As per the Kivy docs, the app_icon is nothing more than a [StringProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.StringProperty)

- [ActionPrevious.app_icon](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.actionbar.html#kivy.uix.actionbar.ActionPrevious.app_icon)

Answer (score -1):

```
ActionPrevious:
   title: 'Recently Available'
   with_previous: False
   app_icon: '' if self.app_icon is not None else "assets/images/P1.png"
```